# jQuery loop through characters in an array of strings and find its index

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

var tags = ["abcd", "aaacd", "ade"];

I'm trying to loop through each string in the array and find its index. Again loop through characters in each string and find its index (eg.)

```
$.each(arr, function( index, value ) {
    $.each(value.split(""), function( i, v ) {
        alert( i + ": " + v );
    });
});
```

Comment: Use `value.split("")` in second loop

Comment: What's your question, exactly, about this?

Comment: @Mohammad -- I tried split. It didin't work$.each(arr, function( index, value ) {
    $.each(value.split(""), function( i, v ) {
        alert( i + ": " + v );
    });
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `split()` the **value** with empty string so that it becomes an array and you can implement `.each()`:

```
value.split('')
```

```js
var tags = ["abcd", "aaacd", "ade"];
$.each(tags, function( index, value ) {
  $.each(value.split(''), function( i, v ) {
    alert( i + ": " + v );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to convert string to array inside first each

```js
var tags = ["abcd", "aaacd", "ade"];
$.each(tags, function( index, value ) {
     var va=value.split('');
    $.each(va, function( i, v ) {
        alert( i + ": " + v );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a nested [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and map at the end the index and value.

```js
var tags = ["abcd", "aaacd", "ade"],
    result = Array.from(tags, (s, i) => Array.from(s, (c, i) => [i, c]));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous way of handling this problem. You could also use the `.entries()` in a `for of loop`:

```js
var tags = ["abcd", "aaacd", "ade"];
for (var val of tags) {
  for (var [idx, char] of val.split('').entries()) {
    console.log(idx + " : " + char);
  }
};
```